# installing zend debugger, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, php.ini, zend

I'm trying to install zend debugger in my ubuntu desktop with php 5.3 which I installed from ubuntu repositories.

I have copied debugger plugin 5.3.x from zend.com to /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs and added the code below to php.ini file located at /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ZendDebugger.so
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
zend_debugger.httpd_uid=-1
```

still after restarting apache there's no sign of zend debugger in phpinfo();

I also tried changing the permissions and owner/group of ZendDebugger.so to 0644 root/root (just like the other plugins in the directory), still not working

any help is appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it can be solved with libssl0.9.8 package.

Comment: Elaborate please.